# Silent Installation for Outlook Add-In

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, installation, outlook-addin

I'm trying to install a Microsoft Outlook Add-In silently.

I already did the installer (.msi, has to be msi) with InstallShield, and at the end of the installation it does put the files in the correct folder and everything.

BUT I need to be able to execute this installer silently without the UserAccount Pop-Up shows up. (I have 'Publisher: Unknown').

[image: UserAccount(Image)]

AND be able to execute the '.vsto' file silently too since that's the one that adds it to Outlook.

[image: dotVSTO Window]

Comment: Installers must run under elevated privileges, which means you can't stop the UAC prompt. You can't bypass that - if you could, then account privilege levels would be pretty useless.

Comment: You may be able to do it by repackaging the install with a product like [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/)

Comment: If you don't want the "Unknown Publisher" you'll need to sign the setup package with a Microsoft Authenticode Code Signing certificate